# How to auto select checkboxes in Android Preference screen?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-checkbox

In my android app, I have a **preference screen** with some **checkboxes**, defined in an xml file and a class that implements `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`.

What I want to do is to select a checkbox and all the other checkboxes to be selected as well. In the above listener, I am able to modify the other checkboxes' state to selected, but my view remains unchanged. What should/could I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your preference should look, but you might want to extend `DialogPreference` and create all checkboxes there.

Comment: well, it's not up to me , I didn't meant that it wouldn't work for me